# Hundreds of 8MB empty journald archives fill up my hard drive

Tags: docker, systemd-journald

I have the following `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` config:

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitIntervalSec=30s
#RateLimitBurst=1000
SystemMaxUse=5G
SystemKeepFree=10G
SystemMaxFileSize=1G
#SystemMaxFiles=100
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
```

In `/var/log/journal` I noticed hundreds of journal archives, that are empty when checked with `journalctl --file ...`:

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 May  8 10:56 system@0005c1cdba211b70-d20ede1ca4e073e9.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 May  8 10:56 system@0005c1cdba212b29-70bbf07dbed15c4d.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 May  8 10:56 system@0005c1cdbac634c6-d54bf6a5900b4ce2.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 May  8 10:57 system@0005c1cdbac67497-e349b1b6f7b2547f.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 May  8 10:57 system@0005c1cdbac6b9d4-1b83111d87f36eb9.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 May  8 10:57 system@0005c1cdbac702c1-e24673835c81e2b6.journal~
```

When I run `journalctl --vacuum-size=500M`, all files disappear, but they very quickly appear again, until after a few minutes my hard drive is full.

This happens only when the docker daemon is running, which is configures with `"log-driver": "journald"`. I can't find any information on why this happens. How can I debug this, what could cause this behaviour?

---

/Edit: This appears even when the docker daemon log-driver is set to `json-file`, but still only when dockerd is running.

---

/Edit 2: It might not have been docker after all. I noticed the same behaviour even when docker was not running, but slower. However, after commenting out all lines in `journal.conf`, the problem disappeared. I suspect that setting  `SystemKeepFree=10G` when initially less than 10G space was available on the hard drive, journald started rotating log files very quickly and filling up the disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away after resetting `journald.conf` to the default (empty file). I suspect that setting `SystemKeepFree=10G` and not having 10GB free space to begin with, journald somehow fell into some sort of rotation loop filling up the disk with empty journal files.